# p:rowExpansion call rowToggle event only on open

Tags: primefaces

I have some code, something like this:

```
<p:rowExpansion>
   <p:datatable>
      <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="methodCall()">
      <p:column>
```

My problem is that the `rowToggle` event is calling the listener on both open and close of the `rowExpansion`.

Is it possible to call the event only on open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a listener that takes the [`ToggleEvent`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/event/ToggleEvent.java) as a parameter. Then you can read the [`Visibility`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/Visibility.java) of that event to determine whether the row was opened or closed.

So, your listener method should look like:

```
public void onRowToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
  if (event.getVisibility() == Visibility.VISIBLE) {
    //...
  }
}
```

And link it without parenthesis in your XHTML using EL:

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{myBean.onRowToggle}"/>
```